# Vertically Concatenating Data Frames in R

Tags: r, dataframe, concatenation

I would like to vertically concatenate two data frames, each of which have the identical column names and structure.

For example, if Dataframe1 and Dataframe2 both have the columns (in the same order) Day, Month and Year, I would like to create Dataset3 with the same columns, Day, Month and Year, but that will contain the data from both Dataset1 and Dataset2. Columns structures are identical.

Thanks,
John

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example and expected output.  When you say concatenate, is it create a vector of values or `paste`.  Perhaps `data.frame(Map(c, Dataframe1, Dataframe2))` or `data.frame(Map(paste, Dataframe1, Dataframe2))` or if you need to rbind them, `rbind(Dataframe1, Dataframe2)`. (without an example it is difficult to know the expected)

Comment: `rbind()` or `dplyr::bind_rows()`, plus anything suggested by @akrun the wise.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.